# For what $n$ is $\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}+\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, puzzle

> For what $n$ is $\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}+\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}$ an integer?

I tried setting $a=\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}$ , $b=\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{625}{4}-n}}$ and playing with their squares/fourth powers, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you call $x = $ that thing, then $$x^2 = 25 + 2 \sqrt{n}$$ This means that $n$ needs to be a square $n=m^2$. Then you can go on with the difference of squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the expression equal to $x$ and square the equation, you get $$x^2=25+2\sqrt{n}.$$ This is equivalent to $$n=\left(\frac{x^2-5^2}{2}\right)^2.$$ So just pick $x$ equal to an odd integer and then this above expression is $n.$

As Crostul points out, in order for the original expression to be well-defined, we need $n$ to be less than or equal to $\frac{625}{4}=156.25.$ And the fact that $n$ is a square means that it must be non-negative.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that $n$ must satisfy the condition $$0 \le n \le 625/4$$ otherwise $x$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Crostul Ah, good point, I hadn't thought out it. I will edit it now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut did you find it by direct search, veryfing all squares less than 156.5?

Comment: @gournge By checking squares. There aren't many of them. But actually $64$ doesn't work, so it's only $0$ and $144$.

Comment: $64$ doesn't work because is arises from setting $x=3$ in the equation $n=\left(\frac{x^2-5^2}{2}\right)^2$. But a glance at the previous equation from which that is derived makes plain that it must be the case that $x\ge 5$. The two solutions that work arise from $x=5,7$, and $x\ge 9$ is ruled out by the limitation $n\le 625/4$